# "show formulas" in excel using python & win32com

Tags: excel, python-3.x, excel-formula, win32com, excel-automation

How can display/show all of the formulas in an Excel workbook using Python3 and win32com.client, like I can do interactively with Cntrl-`

I believe I have to use the [Windows DisplayFormulas Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Window.DisplayFormulas) but I don't know how to access the ActiveWindow to do this in Python.

Here is the code I have up to open a spreadsheet and the first workbook and save it:

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
ws_index_list = [1] 
wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()

# would like to toggle to show the formulas here before saving

wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, pdf_path)
wb.Close(False)
```

From the keyboard I'd simply enter Cntrl-`, I'd like to automate this as I'm processing about 30 excel spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to access the `Window` object of the `Excel` application. You can then call the `DisplayFormulas` method:

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
ws_index_list = [1] 
wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()

#toggle DisplayFormulas
for w in excel.Windows:
   w.DisplayFormulas = True

wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, pdf_path)
wb.Close(False)
```