# How to populate a form from MS Access using PyODBC

Tags: python, database, ms-access, pyodbc

I found the query used to generate the MS Access form, does anyone know if it's possible to call from PyODBC (I'm actually just trying to print it automatically in my script)? The query looks like below. What if it's possible can anyone give an example of what the Python code would look like?

Just an update I found the SQL query itself (below), so is it possible to generate this form with PyODBC and print it out?

```
SELECT ProgramData.ProgramNo, OperationData.OpNo, OperationData.OpDescription, OperationData.StationNo, ProgramData.Machine, ProgramData.CycleTime, ProgramData.[Mat-Piece], ProgramData.FileName, ProgramData.ProgramNotes, ProgramData.Status, ProgramData.PartNumber, PartData.PartName, PartData.Material, PartData.Size, ProgramData.OpNum, ProgramData.BackProgram, OperationData.[B-OpNo], OperationData.[BOpDescription], OperationData.[B-Spindle], OperationData.Spindle, OperationData.LineNum,OperationData.[B-StationNo], OperationData.MillGraphic
FROM (ProgramData INNER JOIN OperationData ON ProgramData.ProgramNo = OperationData.ProgramNo) INNER JOIN PartData ON ProgramData.PartNumber PartData.PartNumber
WHERE (((ProgramData.ProgramNo)=[Forms]![Frm_ProgramData]![ProgramNo]))
ORDER BY OperationData.LineNum;
```

[image]

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking. You can run that query with PyODBC (you'll need to remove the form parameter), but it doesn't do forms. PyODBC only works with the database part of Access and will never touch the forms.

Comment: Well, I guess that answered my question. I wanted to connect with the database and print the form out automatically 

I've been getting `The specified field 'ProgramNo' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.` when trying to interact with the query, do you know how to assign an alias properly to get around this? I don't know the syntax

@ErikvonAsmuth

Comment: That's an unlikely error with this SQL. Have you removed the `WHERE (((ProgramData.ProgramNo)=[Forms]![Frm_ProgramData]![ProgramNo]))` line? Since there's a form-valued parameter in there, PyODBC won't be able to process that properly.

Comment: Also, if you want to print forms, you can do that with Python and COM automation. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52838418/7296893) should be approximately what you need, forms are a bit different from reports but it's not that far off.

Comment: That sounds pretty interesting, I haven't used COM before. I like your example of printing the report, but I don't see how to get queried data from tables into the report or form? I assume this step is missing because you don't have the same thing in reports?

Comment: Access handles that for you. COM essentially just automates actions on the Access application. If you have properly set up the record source in Access, there's nothing more you should do. You can add additional filters if you want, but that's not required.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm ignorant of this process, how does Access handle that for you if I don't enter the query information I want to populate the form?

Comment: Eh... Forms usually don't require information to populate it. If you have a specific setup, you need to share that in the question.